# Python - Blocked thread at os.listdir

Tags: python, multithreading, block, dbus, gobject

I have a mainloop in my program's main thread (The mainloop is a DBusGMainLoop waiting for a disk I/O event), every time an event handler is called a new thread is dispensed for some file copying. The strange thing happens at this point. Suppose an event is called and **thread 1** is started. **Thread 1** blocks at the line '`return os.listdir(path)`' until a second event happens and consequently a **second thread** starts. Then the **thread 1** will continue working fine but **thread 2** blocks. I've also noticed that if I interrupt the mainloop by Ctrl-C both threads will work but obviously the main thread will stop waiting for events.

Can anyone give any hint for why this happens?

This code runs in my main function:

```
mainloop = gobject.MainLoop()
mainloop.run()
```

This is where the event handler starts a new thread:

```
agent = CopyingAgent(mount_point)
agent.start()
```

and this is the method in which the thread **seems** to block or something:

```
def sorted_listdir(self, path):
    return sorted(os.listdir(path))
```

Comment: sounds like a weird conflict between glib and Python's threading implementation. I'm not sure how to solve it but you could consider bypassing the problem by switching to an alternate DBus library: http://packages.python.org/txdbus